# EasyAdmin bundle did not display texts

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I followed the guide step by step. But there are no page title, action names and etc.
Result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye6Og.png)

https://monosnap.com/file/PoLkvZzJFWnmhmJKZOlVMSrIgQgSty

Answer (score 1):

These labels are your strings for translations. Specify, what locale is your default and configure it properly. While you do this, you'll get predefined string translations from EasyAdmin. I figured out the same issue using this code in my app/config.yml:

```
parameters:
    locale: ru

framework:
    translator:  { fallbacks: ["%locale%"], logging: false }
```

As a result I have this output in EasyAdmin:
[image]

Have you also configured EasyAdmin routes? You may have a mistake there also and that can broke your translations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable translator service:

```
# config/packages/translation.yaml
framework:
    translator:
        fallbacks: [ "en" ]
```

However, I already had this enabled and the translation labels were still showing. Deleting of cache did the trick, you need to run:

```
bin/console cache:clear
```